# Kuka LBR iiwa Mastering

Tags: java, master-detail, lbr-iiwa-rapi

I m working with Kuka LBR iiwa and my robot now lost its A1-Mastered position.

I try to get back the Axis within its work-range, but robot does not allow that(I tried it even T1 and KRF modes)

Is any one experince about that problem ? or any other advice for Mastering LBR iiwa(ex: with EMT tool) ?

thanks

Comment: turn the smart pad on T1 modus, go to robot menu and then press the mastering button on that axis that is de referenced, after that switch back to automatic mode...

Comment: btw what is jailbreak doing as a tag here?

Comment: sorry it s wrong tag.

Comment: Also that process I have done . But it does not work. I can t get the A1 in its work-space. So A1 does not move into its work-space. it is stack at -190 (normaly it should be int -170 +170 )

Comment: Did you try with hand movement ptp???

Comment: no I did not. I just unmasterd and that robot lost its orientation (for A1).SO now I can t get it back